# Implement join using bind

Tags: haskell

I am trying to understand how join is implemented using bind (>>=).

```
join x  = x >>= id
```

id has type of (a -> a) but bind needs a function of type (a -> m b). I couldn't match the type.

Comment: `a -> a` unifies with `c -> m b`: we can pick ` a = c = m b`.

Answer (score 7):

If `x` has type `m (m t)`, then `a` is `m t`, so `id` in this context has the type `m b -> m b`, which fits the type of `>>=`.